# Is there a way to check which items got skipped during publishing?

Tags: publishing

I am using Sitecore 8.1 update 1. I wanted to check if there is a way by which I can get a list of skipped items during publishing process? I have come across the Sitecore module that does it but I am not allowed to install any modules at this time.

Hence I was wondering if there is any way I can check the list of skipped items during publishing without installing any modules!

Answer (score 2):

What is your logger level set to? you can change it to Debug and that should show the ID of the items being skipped. This should reflect on the logs the IDs of the items.
In the Sitecore.config change to Debug as in:

```
<logger name="Sitecore.Diagnostics.Publishing" additivity="false"> <level value="INFO" /> <appender-ref ref="PublishingLogFileAppender" /> </logger>
```

Comment: Tried that but didn't work. I checked publishing logs as well as normal logs. Thanks for the pointer though!

Comment: It shows the following:
23868 14:30:20 INFO  [Publishing]: Starting to process 1 publishing options
23868 14:30:20 INFO  [PublishOptions]: root:{5FFCC3B9-326C-445E-B9DA-B5EFE94D0583}, language:en,...
16648 14:30:20 DEBUG [AddLanguagesToQueue] - Languages found : 1
..
16648 14:30:20 DEBUG [ParallelPublishing] MaxDegreeOfParallelism: 4
16648 14:30:20 DEBUG [ParallelPublishing] DisableDatabaseCaches: True
..
16648 14:30:21 INFO  Publish Mode : SingleItem
16648 14:30:21 INFO  Created : 0
16648 14:30:21 INFO  Updated : 34
16648 14:30:21 INFO  Deleted : 0
16648 14:30:21 INFO  Skipped : 4